# Focusing on specific input range of transimpedance amplifier

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, transimpedance-amplifier, spectroscopy

I am trying to make a spectrometer to measure TSS (total suspended solids) in water to that end I'm using a photodiode going into a standard transimpedance amplifier which works as expected if i block the photo diode with something I get 0 V out otherwise I'm getting 3.3 V as was intended.

However when testing with real world samples I cannot see anything. I suspect that the sample is blocking such a small amount of light it gets lost in the ADC response, so going from 100% to 95% while my testing was from 100% to 10%. Is there a way I can limit the amplifier to focus on the upper part of the range so I would get 0 V at say 60% of normal output or below while still getting 3.3 V at 100% to use the full range of the ADC?

I looked a bit perhaps something like a logarithmic response:

https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/op-amp-transimpedance-amplifier/#logarithmic-response

I'm not sure what to even search for.

Comment: You probably don't want to detect the unscattered light since it will be enormously brighter than the scattered signal for relatively clean samples, implying low sensitivity. Easiest solution I think would be to image back or side scatter, all of which would be your signal. If you need forward scatter, I would consider using collimated light and spatially filtering it out before the photodiode. Alternatively you could make the scattering path through the sample extremely long, but that may not be ideal.

Comment: So setting the led and photodiode 90 degrees to each other as oppose to directly in front of one another

Comment: 90 or 180 degrees.  This is easiest, but it will make you a little sensitive to the particle size since large particles scatter more backwards while small particles are isotropic.  You could measure both if you want to be more accurate.  Alternatively, you could design electronics to measure the change in transmitted light.  For example a balanced photodiode could measure the difference between transmission between pure water and the sample of interest.  Then you digitize only the attenuation and not the total light and source noise.  Or you could zero out the pure water photocurrent manually.

Comment: I didn't do a literature search, but since theres a 100 different solutions to this problem, I would probably check which one people think is best before committing.